# Android: song not playing perfectly when seekbar is dragged

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing a music application. SeekBar progress is changing perfectly according to the song, but when I drag the seekbar, song is not playing/dragging perfectly. For ex: when I drag the position of seek bar from 1:20 to 1:50, after dragging, a bit of song(1sec) at 1:20 is playing and then the song is continuing as usual from 1:50. And even while dragging seekbar, song is not dragging smoothly.I had installed 2-3 music apps from market,they play songs smoothly when seekbar is dragged.

Here is the code I had written in my Activity:

```
songSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
   myMediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
   return false;
   }
});
```

Is there any way to achieve smooth progress of song when seekbar is dragged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an `OnTouchListener` here. Instead, use an [`OnSeekBarChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html), this will work much better.